# select from list B k distinct elements that are not in list A in python?

Tags: python, list, selection, disjoint-sets

Suppose unordered `listA = [1 2 3]` s.t all elements distinct
and unordered `listB = [1 2 3 4 5]` s.t all elements distinct

**original question was:** 

How do i choose `len(listA)` times, elements of listB that,
are NOT in listA 
and are distinct from eachother.

**updated to:** 

How do i choose `len(listB)-len(listA)` times, elements of listB that,
are NOT in listA 
and are distinct from eachother.

For the updated case, the answer given by Pynchia becomes:
`newList = list(set(bRightbLeft) - set(aLeft))[:len(bRightbLeft)-len(aLeft))]`

Comment: please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: not sure where it fails the MVC?

Comment: please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example

Comment: I would say the logic of the question is a little malformed, as @Pynchia points out: it might not be possible/reasonable to choose `len(a)` times to get distinct elements that are NOT in `a`. Unless you know for a fact that there will be at least `len(a)` distinct, not-in-`a` elements in `b`. That sounds like a bizarre constraint, so more out of curiosity, I'd love to hear the motivating real-world use-case.

Comment: the motivating real world use case is:
`A = [1 2 3 4 5]` is an allelle
`B = [5 4 3 2 1]` is an allele 
and i want to cross the allelles at a locus.
so i get `a = [1 2]` from A and then make `k = len(a)` distinct selections from B that are not already in A, because for the specific application of the crossover, C needs to be distinct child as its parents are distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick, if I understand correctly

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = [1,2,3,4,5]

newlist = list(set(listB) - set(listA))[:len(listA)]
print(newlist)
```

it produces

```
[4, 5]
```

As you can see, there is no guarantee the list has enough number of elements (i.e. the size of `listA`)

note: initially (and even now partially) the description said the elements in the input lists could be repeated.

In that case, use

```
listA = [1,2,3,2,1]
listB = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]

set_A = set(listA)
newlist = list(set(listB) - set_A)[:len(set_A)]
```

which produces

```
[4, 5]
```

Comment: `as` is keyword ?
on renaming as and bs i get None result.
Im not sure i fully understand your example, thanks for the answer though.
Please read my question update.

Comment: it makes sense now. its late and i couldnt think of set difference to solve this. gah :( thanks again.

Comment: see my edit, which solves the problem even for lists with repeated elements

Comment: updated question to match my usecase and to take out vacuities. might make ur answer incorrect. apologies.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care which elements you could do

```
newList = [ b for b in bList if set(b) not in aList][0:k]
```